# How to get the time we shot the aliens?

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911823/algorithm-dynamic-program), I tried to write the algorithm in python.

here is my code:

```
def shoot(aliens):

    s=[0]*1000
    s[0]=0
    s[1]=1
    num=len(aliens)
    for j in xrange(2,num):
        a=[0]*1000
        for i in xrange(0,j):
            a[i]=s[i]+min(int(aliens[j]),f[j-i]) ## possible tries
        s[j]=max(a)                      ##f[i] is the i-th finonacci number 

    return s[len(aliens)-1]
```

it's working by showing the maximum aliens being destroyed.
However, I want to print out the time they shot aliens.
my idea is to go from the last kill, which is at len(aliens)-1 and find out what the last shoot is before the "(len(aliens)-1)"-th shoot. and then keep do the same thing until we reach the first shoot.

To do that, I stored all possible tries and compared the last shoot to them to find the second last shoot, but the running time would be so long, and it showed the wrong result. 
Im not sure it's right or not, but I tried to implement it but I failed.

Does anyone have an idea for that?
thank you!

PS: please ask me if you dont get what I wrote. also, I do not want to copy the question from the thread above because it's quite long. if it bothers you, I am sorry.

Comment: Your code is incomprehensible. What do the elements of `s`, `a`, or `aliens` mean?

Comment: I believe aliens is an array defining the number of aliens appearing each minute, and a is the number of aliens destroyed if the EMP were fired at that minute. s is the maximum number of aliens destroyed in each minute (which is state in the linked thread).

Comment: ...oh, wow. This is a classic C buffer overflow, in Python. You're lucky Python gives nice IndexErrors instead of corrupting your memory if the aliens attack for more than 1000 minutes.

Comment: If aliens are attacking for more than 1000 minutes, corrupted memory won't be your first concern. If I were you, I'd worry about abduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you got the fibonacci numbers from (the original recursive relation had (j - i)^2)

Regardless, the easiest way would be to keep track of a parent array while doing the dp. For example:

```
def getTimes(aliens):
    n = len(aliens)
    dp = [0] * n #your s array. I'm just used to using dp for dp tables
    parent = [-1] * n
    dp[1] = 1
    for i in range(2, n):
        max = 0; #assuming there can't be a negative number of aliens. 
        for j in range(0, i):
            x = dp[j] + min(int(aliens[i]), (i - j) * (i - j))
            if(x >= max):
                max = x
                parent[i] = j
        dp[i] = max;
    times = getTimesRec(n - 1, [], parent)
    return times

def getTimesRec(i, times, parent):
    if(i == -1):
        return times
    getTimesRec(parent[i], times, parent)
    times.append(i)
    return times
```

I haven't tested this, but the idea behind it should be fine. Essentially whenever you figure out when the last alien was shot you keep track of it in the parent array. You can then go from the end and store the times into a list in reverse order recursively (as shown) or using a stack.

You could also probably make this run in O(nlogn) by using a binary search similar to longest increasing subsequence. I'm too lazy to think about how to do it.

Edit: Hopefully I can clear up some of the confusion. All the parent array does is store when the previous shot occurred given a time frame.

So for example let's say that you shoot at time 4, 19, and 23. This means that the parent array looks like this:

```
parent[23] = 19
parent[19] = 4
parent[4] = -1
```

So given this array we can figure out the reverse order of times by just adding 23 to a list then parent[23] then parent[parent[23]] and so on until we reach -1. The recursion is just there to reverse this chain all in one step.

Comment: One of those functions needs to be renamed, or the second one will replace the first. Also, no parentheses on `for` loops or `if` statements; I don't think the `for` loops will actually compile.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. It's been a while since I coded in python

Comment: there is a little bit different with the question on the thread above as I use Fibonacci numbers instead. anw, thank you to give me the answer. it seems to work fine. However, I need to work on it a little bit, because I do not understand it clearly. Hopefully you can help me if I have a question related to it. Thank you again! @user2357112 is there any error on his post? please tell me.